# Boot Linux Mint from USB in Legacy Mode

Tags: linux-mint, boot, system-installation, dual-boot, uefi

I have an Asus-X550LD with Windows 7 installed, and for the past few hours I have been **unsuccessfully trying to install Linux Mint on my machine in order to create a dual boot system**.

I wrote the Mint image file into a USB using Rufus with the option **"MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI"**. But when I tried to install after booting into the Live version, I got the following error:

> **Force UEFI Installation**
>  This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing
>   operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode".
>   If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult
>   to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later.
>
> If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the
>   ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to
>   force that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing
>   operating system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation
>   here.

When I searched around the internet, I found that I needed to boot in Legacy mode instead of UEFI mode. But, I can't seem to do that from my BIOS.

Following are some screenshots of my BIOS:[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

As you can see in Image 1, the only option I have is to boot my USB in UEFI. I changed other settings, but still can't seem to boot it in Legacy mode.

How do I solve this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How do you create the bootable USB?

Comment: If you have create the bootable USB through Rufus to boot Legacy and UEFI , Clic on the "Boot option #1" , you will see your USB listed 2 time : the first to boot on the EFI mode and the 2 nd to boot the legacy mode

Comment: @GAD3R I use the Boot Option #1/"MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI" while creating the bootable USB in Rufus. But still, I don't get the option to boot in Legacy. I just have this option: "UEFI: SanDisk" (Image 1). When I click on "Hard Drive BBS Priorties" (Image 1), it just mentions "SanDisk". Nowhere did I find "Legacy"/"BIOS" together with "SanDisk"

Comment: @GAD3R I do get the option to start Mint in "Compatibility Mode" when I boot from the USB, but this still gives me the "Force UEFI Installation" message when I try to install

Comment: Yes there are a problem when trying to install some linux disto on legacy boot on Asus-X550...., Forcing the installation will break windows and the linux mint will not be installed correctly.

Comment: @GAD3R So what do I do then? Does this mean I cannot install Linux as a dual OS on my machine? :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to change "Launch CMS" from "enable" to "DISABLE". 
If you still have problem after this, you'll have to create a non UEFI usb live.